# How do I use data from the previous page after changing url with router.push()?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In nextjs 13 using the App Router, I have a `/quiz` page. When a user finishes the quiz it will save their results to my database and then redirect the user to `/results`. The results page uses the data that was just saved.

Right now on the `/results` page I'm making a `get` request to the database for the object that was just saved, which feels pretty silly since the data was already there. I think what I had wanted to do is

Comment: Why don't you just use tanstack-query or SWR? They automatically make your data from server cached.

Comment: Loading it from the sever is the best option in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this:

- You can use any kind of state management like useContext or redux to save and retrieve the result
- Or you can save the result in cookies and retrieve it in the result page

But I think it's better to get the result from a GET request in the result page, because if the there are other unhandled user scenarios like if the user can access the results page later directly, he will need a GET request to fetch his results score, or if you allow retesting...etc or any other scenarios.